# How can i remove portions of audio instead of concatenate the portions

Tags: ffmpeg

If i've got this command that concatenates audio between 115-368 seconds and 605 to the end and the output only has this audio.

```
ffmpeg -i "abc.mp3" -filter_complex "[0:a]atrim=start=115:end=368,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[ba];[0:a]atrim=start=605,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[da]" -b:a 320k "def.mp3"
```

How can i make this same command so that instead of the output being concatenation of these 2, it removes these two portions and the output has the remaining audio in it

I know there's a way where i can just instead get the start and end of the audio i want and concatenate those, but i'd like to know for my knowledge if there is a way to remove the audio, rather than concatenate into the output.

Comment: so do you want to insert silence over 115-368 and 605-?

Comment: @kesh Not silence, i'd like my final output audio to not have the bits from 115-368 and 605-

Comment: Then, what you know is the way to go: just do what you've already done with `atrim` but different starting and ending times.

Answer (score 1):

It's a somewhat confusing question but if what you want to achieve by the words, `remove rather than concatenate`, is a simple silence during certain periods, you could simply chain the `volume` filter.

e.g.:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -af "volume=enable='between(t,0,15)':volume=0,volume=enable='between(t,30,45)':volume=0" out.mp3
```

Would give you the entire audio but with silence at the start for 15 seconds and silence between seconds 30 to 45.